# Make Spring boot application Startup Faster

Tags: java, performance, spring-boot, applicationcontext, lazy-initialization

There are two IOC containers in spring-boot: `BeanFactory` and `ApplicationContext`.

As per my understanding, `ApplicationContext` supports the eager initialization of beans where `BeanFactory` does it lazily.

**Problem Statement:** In my Spring boot application, I wanna use lazy initialization of beans to make application startup faster. Can anyone please suggest the solution for achieving the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lazy initialization property:

```
spring.main.lazy-initialization=true
```

This property is only supported in spring boot 2.2 and above. You will need to write a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` if version is less than 2.2. This property will make sure that the dependencies are not to be injected until it's needed, the main difference in timing can be seen when hot restart is performed.

FYI `ApplicationContext` *is a* `BeanFactory`, both supports lazy init. It really depends on when `BeanFactory#getBeanProvider` was invoked.

Comment: Will this property make the app use the IOC containers as "BeanFactory"?

Comment: Could you please add some explanation?

Comment: It will use the ApplicationContext. App Context is inherrited from the BeanFactory, enhance it. Default it will load all beans on startup. You can set up BF programmaticly of course, but I suggest use AC in production without lazy loading, so you will see bean creation exceptions on load time. In dev mode, you can use the property, Aniket suggest to you, so the startup time will be decreased.

Answer (score 5):

Explanation about Aniket Sahrawat answer: `spring.main.lazy-initialization=true`

**Effects of Lazy Initialization**

Enabling lazy initialization in the whole application could produce both positive and negative effects.

Let's talk about some of these, as they're described in the official announcement of the new functionality:

1. Lazy initialization may reduce the number of beans created when the
   application is starting – therefore, we can improve the startup time
   of the application
2. As none of the beans are created until they are needed, we could
   mask issues, getting them in run time instead of startup time
3. The issues can include out of memory errors, misconfigurations, or
   class-definition-found errors
4. Also, when we're in a web context, triggering bean creation on
   demand will increase the latency of HTTP requests – the bean
   creation will affect only the first request, but this may have a
   negative impact in load-balancing and auto-scaling.

Reference: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-lazy-initialization#effects

Comment: More information about: https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/14/lazy-initialization-in-spring-boot-2-2